# Slim4 and PHP-DI doesn't inject using annotation

Tags: php, dependency-injection, php-8.1, php-di, slim-4

I'm migrating a project from an older version of Slim and PHP-DI to the last one and PHP 8.1.17.

These are the composer dependency for slim and php-di:

```
"slim/slim" : "~4.11",
"php-di/php-di" : "^7.0.2",
```

PHP-DI annotation doesn't work like the previous one and I cannot understand why.

This is the main entry file:

```
use DI\ContainerBuilder;


$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->useAttributes(true);

$dependencies = require __DIR__ . '/../src/dependencies.php';
$dependencies($containerBuilder);


$app = $container->get(App::class);

(require __DIR__ . '/../src/middleware.php')($app);


$app->run();
```

This is the container bootstrap file (dependencies.php):

```
return function (ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder) {
    //config
    $containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
        App::class => function (ContainerInterface $container) {
            $app = AppFactory::createFromContainer($container);
            return $app;
        },
        
}
```

This is the middleware import file (middleware.php):

```
return function (App $app) {

    $app->add($app->getContainer()->get(SystemMiddleware::class));
};
```

And this is the SystemMiddleware implementation:

```
final class SystemMiddleware implements MiddlewareInterface
{
    #[Inject]  
    protected App $app;
    
    
    public function process(ServerRequestInterface $request, RequestHandlerInterface $handler): ResponseInterface
    {
        $this->app
        //^^^^^^^^^ here app is not initialized!
        return $handler->handle($request);
    }
}
```

Currenctly I have to pass $app to SystemMiddleware constructor, but why #[Inject] doesn't work? What I'm missing?